# react-router and typescript throwing "Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

As I am new to react and typescript this is probably a simple mistake, but I have checked other answers I found about this and nothing has worked. I would appreciate any help and an explanation of what I am doing wrong so I can learn.  I cannot seem to get react-router to work with typescript at all.  It keeps throwing an error that it "can't resolve react-router-dom" in the following code.  I attempted to follow a basic tutorial for react-router and typescript I found here:
https://riptutorial.com/react-router/example/30226/basic-routing

So basically what I want to happen is for the login screen to come up with Username and Password fields to pop up and a submit button underneath it.  Then underneath that I have a link that they can click on to register if they don't already have an account, which will take them to another page.

I will put the Register class in its own file and import it once this works, I just didn't want to have to show two different files for the example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';

interface IState {
    [key: string]: any; // or the type of your input
} 

const styles = {
    background: 'lightblue'
};

export class Login extends React.Component<{}, IState> {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            authorized: false
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    }


    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]:value
        });
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
      //TODO: we are going to submit the form to the database
        event.prevent.default();
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <TextField
                        id="username"
                        name="username"
                        label="UserName"
                        helperText="Enter your Username"
                        value={this.state.username}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        required={true}
                        style={styles}
                    />

                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        helperText="Enter your password"
                        label="Password"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        required={true}
                        style={styles}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br/>
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        value="Submit"
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"

                    >Submit</Button>   
                    <br />
                    <br/>
                    <Alert variant="info">
                        <Alert.Heading>Don't Have An Account Setup?</Alert.Heading>
                        <div>
                            <Link to="/register">Register Here</Link>
                        </div>
                    </Alert>
                </form>


            </div>

        )

    }
}

class Register extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Register</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        </div>
    </Router>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I think you successfully installed react-router-dom, right?

Comment: @FurkanO yes, I have react router dom and the typings installed...there are no errors showing, but an error gets thrown when attempting to compile

Comment: Have you tried deleting `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again?

Answer (score 3):

You just have to install the @types (@types/react-router-dom) that provide the types definition and install react-router-dom:

```
npm install -S react-router-dom @types/react-router-dom
```

or

```
yarn add react-router-dom @types/react-router-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redirect of react-router-dom to use redirect like below

```
import {  Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
render() {
       if(condition===true){
              return (                 
                <Redirect to='/your-route-path' />
              ) 

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for a workaround, I'm trying to understand why the normal way of doing it is not working so I can learn what I am doing wrong.